# Laravel: Inject Auth into a Service

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How do I inject `Auth` into a service? I know in the service itself, I do:

```
public function __construct(Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager $Auth)
{
    $this->authService = $Auth;
}
```

But how do I pass it in the service provider? I.e.

```
$this->app->bind('SomeService', function() {
    return new SomeService(??); // What goes here?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should allow the laravel app to build an object based on your dependency here. I haven't tried this myself but looks like this might work:

```
return new SomeService(App::make(Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager));
```